# execute relational query with django orm

Tags: python, django, orm

I have this model in my django application:

```
class Buyer(model.Model):
    username = ...
    ...

class Seller(model.Model):
    username = ...
    ...

class Stuff(model.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller)
    ....

class BuyerStuff(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)
    stuff = models.ForeignKey(Stuff)
    ...
```

I want to get all stuffs that related to specific seller that buyer for example order that stuff. I can do this with raw sql but I want to know is there any way to do this with django ORM?

Comment: Do you want to get the seller specific items or buyer related items?

Comment: @limelights assume buyers order some of the stuffs that belong to specific seller, I want to show the seller which stuff ordered by buyers

Comment: Are you looking for this => `BuyerStuff.objects.filter(stuff__seller=seller).select_related(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for reverse relation ships?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

also have a look at the 'related_name' model property... nice to use in reverse lookups.

Answer (score 0):

By default FK reverses are named `{model}_set`

So in your case:

```
john = Buyer.objects.get(pk=5)
john_stuff = john.buyerstuff_set.all()
```

But using `related_name`s is a bit easier to remember.

If your model was like:

```
class BuyerStuff(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)
    stuff = models.ForeignKey(Stuff, related_name='stuff')
    ...
```

john_stuff = john.stuff.all()

But if you want to query against FK:

```
buyer = BuyerStuff.objects.filter(buyer__pk=5)
```

And at last `select_related` and `fetch_related`, are performance optimization (JOINs). `select_related` is used in One-to-X scenarios, `prefetch_related` in Many-to-X scenarios.